# Ensure processing order with multiple consumer

Tags: queue, jms

I have 2 requests (A and B) sent to queue in order. However, there are 2 consumers and they process 2 requests at the same time.

**Question**: How do I ensure 2 requests will be processed in order (A completed 1st then B will be processed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html, you can set "JMSXGroupID" to ensure processing order with multiple consumers